# How to connect Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless in Alienware

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros, alienware

I need your help. I can not connect my Dell Alienware 14 with **Qualcomm Atheros AR9462.** I've searched several forun and it does not work.

Anyone could guide me please.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Comment: Ready!!!!                                                                                                                                $sudo aptitude install linux-headers-generic build-essentials

Comment: $cd Descargas
$tar -xvf compat-wireless-3.6.8-1
$cd compat-wireless-3.6.8-1
$sudo su
#./scripts/driver-select ath9k
#make
#make install
#exit

Comment: $sudo make unload
$sudo modprobe ath9k

Comment: reboot                  $cd compat-wireless-3.6.8-1
$sudo su
#./scripts/driver-select restore
#./scripts/driver-select ath9k
#make clean
#make
#make install
#exit

$sudo make unload
$sudo modprobe ath9k

Comment: reboot                            !!!!!!!!!

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)